# How to use ng.material.MdDialog in ES5?

Tags: angular, material-design

We need to use ES5 flavor of Angular 2, and Material 2.

We're stuck at using material's dialog. What we've done so far is:

```
var parentComponent = ng.core.Component({
    templateUrl: '/parentComponent.html'
    selector: 'parentComponent'
}).Class({
    constructor: [app.material.MdDialog, function(dialog) {
        var _this = this;
        _this.dialog = dialog;
    }],
    openDialog: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var reference = _this.dialog.open(' ? what goes here?');
    }
});

var dialogComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'dialogComponent',
    templateUrl: '/dialogComponent.html'
}).Class({
    constructor: [ng.material.MdDialogRef, function(dialogRef) {
        var _this = this;
        _this.dialogRef = dialogRef;
        // why do we need dialog ref at all?
    }]
});
```

And when we call `_this.dialog.open`, we encounter this error:

```
caused by: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

We can't find a working example of `MdDialog` and we can't solve this issue either. Anyone can help?

Comment: can you post your NgModule file?

Comment: You need to register the `dialogComponent` to the `entryComponents`of the parent module.

Comment: @cgatian, where and how in ES5? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Never did ES5. But its probably where you declare the components as a part of the module.  Components displayed via the md-dialog need to be registered in both declarations, and entrycomponents.